# Add header to PlayReadyLicenseAcquisitionServiceRequest using Javascript WinRT

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-runtime

I'm having quite a bit of trouble figuring out how to do something I think would be simple. Prior to initializing a video stream, the DRM server gives our app a token to use in the authorization header. In our code, we are using the MediaProtectionManager that is part of PlayReady. When a license call is needed, the manager sends the request through a callback function. Presumably, I should be able to add a header to that request prior to awaiting the result, but I do not see any methods on it. The request is of type PlayReadyLicenseAcquisitionServiceRequest.

```
const setupDRM = (onServiceRequested) => {
  const { MediaProtectionManager } = window.Windows.Media.Protection;
  const manager = new MediaProtectionManager();
  // other setup steps excluded for readability...
  manager.addEventListener('servicerequested', onServiceRequested, false);
};


const onServiceRequested = async (event) => {
  const { request } = event;
  appendToken(request); // Add authorization header with token
  const result = await request.beginServiceRequest();
};

const appendToken = (request) => {
   // How do I do this?
}
```

Now, I have found similar questions answered, but only in C#. In all those cases, the answer is to clone the request as an HTTP request, add the headers, and await the result.

```
public static async Task<bool> RequestLicenseManual(PlayReadyLicenseAcquisitionServiceRequest request, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] headers)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("ProtectionManager PlayReady Manual License Request in progress");

  try
  {
    var r = request.GenerateManualEnablingChallenge();

    var content = new ByteArrayContent(r.GetMessageBody());

    foreach (var header in r.MessageHeaders.Where(x => x.Value != null))
    {
      if (header.Key.Equals("Content-Type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(header.Value.ToString());
      }
      else
      {
        content.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value.ToString());
      }
    }

    var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, r.Uri) { Content = content };

    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
      msg.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value.ToString());
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Requesting license from {0} with custom data {1}", msg.RequestUri, await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.SendAsync(msg);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      request.ProcessManualEnablingResponse(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
    }
    else
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("ProtectionManager PlayReady License Request failed: " + await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

      return false;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("ProtectionManager PlayReady License Request failed: " + ex.Message);

    return false;
  }

  Debug.WriteLine("ProtectionManager PlayReady License Request successfull");

  return true;
}
```

I've been able to reproduce this somewhat in JavaScript, but cannot seem to find a way to convert the byte array returned by getMessageBody into anything that is usable and cannot find an equivalent of ByteArrayContent in the WinRt API. In any case, this all seems like overkill. Shouldn't it just be as easy as calling a set header function on the request?

Comment: I've encountered the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorta. I've converted the C# code over to Javascript and also Typescript, but the major sticking point, seems there are differences between HttpBufferContent and ByteArrayContent. The former is available to Js, but whenever read as a buffer from the content of the body, all I get are content headers and the body of the soap request is wiped out. The HttpClient available on the WinRt side also appears to work differently and is in a different namespace than C# leading to difficulties setting a proper auth header. Thx for responding. I've only heard crickets so far since I started this question.

Comment: FYI, the C# code works perfectly, but I'm pretty much the only dev on my team who understands C#, and so the desire is that whatever we do, we do it in JavaScript for the sake of maintainability in the future. Otherwise, I would have just used C# and be done with it!

Comment: Hey.  Not sure if it helps but I think I've addressed getting ByteArrayContent into a format suitable for the WinRt methods (iBuffer). I'm still not getting successful playback on XBox One (which might be due to headers).



`var r = request.generateManualEnablingChallenge();

var byteArray = r.getMessageBody();

var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter();

dataWriter.writeBytes(byteArray);

var iBuffer = dataWriter.detachBuffer();

var content = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpBufferContent(iBuffer);
`

Comment: I haven’t tried DataWriter yet, but I did get the C# side working in conjunction with the JS side and converted to number[]. It doesn’t seem to matter if the request comes through successfully. Process the result with the request on the JS or the C# side, it just gets ignored when calling processManuallyEnablingResponse whether on either side. Thing is that the video element is tied to the DRM manager on the JS side. There is no purpose for calling this method in JS because it says success, but doesn’t actually do anything.